# `arguments` used in inner function/arraow function behave differently

Tags: javascript

`t1` and `t2` returns a function in different way, a normal function or an arrow function:

```
function t1(fn) {
    return async function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}

function t2(fn) {
    return async () => {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}

t1('t1: outer arg')('t1: inner arg');
t2('t2: outer arg')('t2: inner arg');
```

This surprised me, because I thought the normal form of the function and the arrow function notations are inter-exchangeable almost.

```
$ node arguments_scope.js 
[Arguments] { '0': 't1: inner arg' }
[Arguments] { '0': 't2: outer arg' }
```

Why?

Comment: [Don't use `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), use `(...args)=>console.log(args)` instead.

Comment: Arrow functions, among other things, don't have their own `arguments`, so that value is coming from the closure. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions